# Who are the speakers of the other gitas?

Tags: gita

Bhagavad Gita is the most famous gita. There are two opinions regarding who spoke Bhagavad Gita, one group says it is Krishna and the others says it is Brahman that Krishna was connected to.

This is justified using this quote from [Anugita](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m14/m14016.htm)

> परं हि बरह्म कथितं यॊगयुक्तेन तन मया param hi brahma kathitaM
> yogayuktena tanmayA [Krishna said:]
>
> I discoursed to thee on Supreme
> Brahma, having concentrated myself in Yoga.(KM Ganguly's translation)
>
> I immersed myself in yoga and told you about the supreme brahman(Bibek Debroy's translation)

There are other gitas like Devi Gita, Ishwara gita etc..

Does the second group believe that it is Brahman connection through Yoga which enabled the respective deities to speak? If yes, does it have scriptural basis like the above one for Krishna? Or the deities themselves speaking here without connection to Brahman through Yoga?

I am not interested in all the gitas, that will make it too broad. Answer can be just for the above  gitas that I mentioned.

Comment: there are around sixty gitas.kindly search the netvand you wd get them listed in single site

Comment: @ParthaBanerjee I know that. I just listed a few.

Comment: yes, deities are speaking.And theyvare parts of different puranas

Comment: So only when Krishna speaks it's brahman battery that powers him. Otherwise it's all just deities

Comment: this can not be known from that gita alone. from anugita the inference is being made about bhagavadgita.

Comment: @parthabanerjee So then we can infer and conclude that only Krishna had access to Brahman... Because he is verily that. Now how many would accept that? Lol.

Comment: @Ambi at least i wont

Comment: @parthabanerjee And I fully respect that stand as mentioned in my profile too. Not many repay that courtesy.